# Java : Semaphore: Producer Consumer: Threads and ThreadGroup

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, producer-consumer

I have Implemented a semaphore class for producer and consumer.

It is working fine, But I am feeling now that we use notifyAll to notify the threads which awakes or notifies all the threads.

I want to know if there is any way in which we can notify only a particular set of groups: like producers only notify consumer threads and vice-versa using groups or anything else.

PS: I am new to java and Threading.

Comment: What are the rules for these groups?  If they do not overlap, there is no problem - just use a different queue, (and so semaphore), for each group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me like you're reinventing the wheel. [Semaphores](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) are available in the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Besides, for a producer / consumer datastructure, I'd suggest you simply use a `BlockingQueue`.

Anyway, the `notify` method notifies one (unspecified) waiter. If you indeed need a specific "order" on which ones to let through, I believe you would have to `notifyAll` and "manually" make sure only the relevant ones are allowed to acquire the semaphore.

---

For you particular case, it seems to me like you need one wait-set for producers, and one wait-set for consumers. Since you have one wait set per object, it is impossible to notify only the consumers (or producers) using one object. Perhaps what you're after is having two objects, one acquired by producers, and one acquired by consumers, and then do `consumerObj.notifyAll()`, or `producerObj.notifyAll()`, depending on which group of threads you want to wake up.

Comment: But Still My question stays, if there is any way in which I can notify only a set of threads or a threadgroup?

Comment: Right, my answer is, no, not to the extent of my knowledge. You'd have to implement such functionality *on top of* the `notify` / `notifyAll` primitives.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread arr [] = new Thread[10];          
        ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("test");
        group.enumerate(arr);
        group.notifyAll();
```

Comment: Uhm, `group.notifyAll` will notify all threads that have run `synchronize (group) { ... wait(); ... }`